# What's the appropriate phrase for 'unsubscribe', with regards to an electronic mailing list?

Tags: single-word-request

Google Translate is suggesting 'abmelden', but I'm wondering if there's a more commonly used idiom that could go at the bottom of an email or otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Abo kündigen**. (*Abo* is a universally understood short form of *Abonnement* - subscription, *kündigen* is to terminate.)

*Abmelden* will confuse some people as it is most commonly used on the Web for "logging out" (e.g., from a forum).

[**Mailman**](http://www.list.org/), perhaps the most widely used mailing list manager, uses two different translations for "unsubscribe" on its standard user-facing "About" page ([**example**](http://lists.d-nb.de/mailman/listinfo/metamorph)):

1. Bezug der Liste kündigen
2. Abonnement abbestellen

I find them both inferior to my proposal, which wins on grounds of brevity.

Comment: Ich glaube kaum dass "abmelden" jemanden verwirren wird, zumal nicht Abonennten einer Mailingliste, und vor allem deshalb nicht, weil sich fast niemand je irgendwo explizit ausloggt. Eine Alternative ist das Kündigen des Abos (wieso nicht der Liste?) sicher, aber an abmelden oder abbestellen ist auch nichts auszusetzen.

Answer (score 4):

To add some more alternatives to the [nice answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/5974/23) given already:

> - Newsletter abbestellen  (*both "Abonnement", and "kündigen" don't go well with Newsletters*)
> - Von der Empfängerliste streichen
> - [In Zukunft] keine Benachrichtigungen mehr erhalten
> - Aus dem Verteiler nehmen

Answer (score 2):

Ich kenne noch: "können Sie mich bitte (aus Ihrer Liste) austragen?"